# Question regarding reading lines from a file in C

Tags: c, file

```
  int line = 0;
        char input[MAX_INPUT_SIZE];
        while(fgets(input, MAX_INPUT_SIZE, inputFile))
        {
            printf("%s", input);
            line++;
        }
```

This is a piece from a code I wrote to experiment with file reading in C. (I have already checked if the pointer to the file is not null at this point).

Also, `MAX_INPUT_SIZE = 1025.`

I was wondering, what happens when I will read a really big file, what happens to `input` each time I use fgets?

Does fgets just randomly writes into `input?` how can I know to where each line that I read starts and ends in `input?`

Would love to get some insight, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering, what happens when I will read a really big file, what happens to `input` each time I use fgets?

The prior contents of `input` are over-written.

> how can I know to where each line that I read starts and ends in input?

**Short story**

`fgets()` reads a *line* (text up to and including the `'\n'`) into a *string* (characters up to the appended terminating *null character*).

The line's characters starts with `input[0]`.

The number of characters read is `strlen(input)`

---

**Longer story**

A *line* in C usually has a terminating `'\n'`.  The last *line* of input may/may not have a `'\n'`.

> each line consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character. Whether the last line requires a terminating new-line character is implementation-defined.  C17dr § 7.21.2 2

**`fgets()` stops early**

```
char *fgets(char * restrict s, int n, FILE * restrict stream);
```

`fgets()` reads data and then appends a *null character*.

`fgets()` stops reading under 4 conditions:

1) A `'\n'` is read.

2) `n-1` characters read.

3) end-of-file occurred.

4) Input error occurred (rare).

For learner code, it is sufficient to supply a large input buffer much like OP's code and check the return value.  For me I would use a 2x size length buffer of the largest *expected* size.

```
char input[MAX_INPUT_SIZE * 2];
while(fgets(input, sizeof input, inputFile)) {
  input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = '\0'; // Lop off potential \n if desired.
  ...
}
```

**Reading null characters**

A `'\0'` is rarely encountered whist reading, yet possible. It messes up the use of `strlen()` to find the read character count.  To handle such gets into other code  likely beyond OP's need now.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of errors, reading stops with a newline or when the buffer is full.

```
fgets(buf, SIZE, f);
len = strlen(buf);
if (buf[len - 1] == '\n') {
    //full line read from file
    //buf[len+1] to buf[SIZE-1] are not changed from their previous values
} else {
    //very long line in file
    //repeat fgets for more of the line
    //if len != SIZE-1 there was some error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you open the file to read, the file pointer will point to the begin of this file. if you want to change the line that you want to start, using `fseek`:

```
int fseek(FILE *stream, long offset, int whence);
```

`fgets` will get line by line in this file (not randomly).

From the `man page`:

```
 char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);
```

> fgets()  reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and
>          stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  **Reading  stops  after  an
>          EOF  or a newline**.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.
>          A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the  last  character  in
>          the buffer